# C++ explicit template for destructor nested classes?

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

This is my scenario (for brevity I have taken out the permissions and instance variables, only the relevant methods):

```
template <typename ItemType>
class LinkedList
{
    class Item
    {
        Item(ItemType theObj, bool freeObj);
        ~Item();
    };

    void add(LinkedList<ItemType>::Item item);
};

template <typename ItemType>
LinkedList<ItemType>::Item::~Item()
{
    if(freeObj) {
        delete obj;
    }
}
```

In my code I used it like this:

```
// works great
LinkedList<MyObject*> mylist;
mylist.add(LinkedList<MyObject*>::Item(new MyObject(), false));

// won't compile because you cannot use delete operator on a non-pointer
LinkedList<MyObject> mylist;
mylist.add(LinkedList<MyObject>::Item(MyObject(), false));
```

Let's put aside the fact that LinkedList<>::Item should not free the actual object. This is more of an understanding templates question. I need to specify an explicit template for the Item destructor to handle when ItemType is a pointer and when its not.

Is this possible? What are some potential design/leak pit falls? Thanks.

Comment: `for brevity I have taken out the permissions` And by doing so you have totally broken the example. Where is your [testcase](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/), pal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for [*partial template specialization*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445593/c-partial-template-specialization-syntax). What you can do is special case for a `ItemType *` and have your internal `Item`'s destructor not perform the delete. Something along the lines of:

```
// General form
template <typename ItemType>
class LinkedList
{
public:
    class Item
    {
        Item(ItemType theObj, bool);
        ~Item() {}
    };

    void add(Item item);
};

// specialize for when ItemType is a pointer
template <typename ItemType>
class LinkedList <ItemType *>
{
public:
    class Item
    {
        Item(ItemType *theObj, bool freeObj);
        ~Item() 
        {
          if(freeObj) delete obj;
        }
    };

    void add(Item item);
};
```

**Edit:** Responding to your first comment. I think you may be able to accomplish this without too much code duplication even without relying on SFINAE. What I would do is move `freeObj` as a non-type parameter to `LinkedList` and keep `class Item` private. The wrapper is just an implementation detail and client code has no business knowing about it. Here's what the proposed alternative would look like:

```
template <typename ItemType, bool freeObj = false>
class LinkedList
{
    template <typename T> 
    class Item
    {
        T obj;
    public:
        Item(T theObj);
        ~Item();
    };
    template <typename T>
    class Item <T *>
    {
        T *obj;
    public:
        Item(T *theObj);
        ~Item() { if(freeObj) delete obj; }
    };

public:
    void add(ItemType) {}
};
```

Here's a [**simple demo example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0546d2c5748cfc90).

Comment: Thanks! ... I have a lot of methods for LinkedList as well and the subclasses SynchronizedLinkedList / UnsynchronizedLinkedList. Is it possible to move all the methods from LinkedList into LinkedListAbstract and extend that so that I only have to implement the Item destructors, or do I have to basically have to have two whole copies of LinkedList which almost exactly the template code duplicated?

Comment: There's a way to specialize the `Item` class to use one implementation if it's a pointer and a different implementation for non-pointers probably using SFINAE technique like [`std::enable_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/enable_if/)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: *don't*. When I have a container of pointers, I do not expect the container to own the *pointees*. In fact, nobody expects this, and the standard library containers do not work this way.

If nothing else, you're making a big mess of memory management by making illogical assumptions about how each element's pointee was allocated and about who owns them.

*The list did not `new` these pointees, so it shall not `delete` them.* Simples!